# Why are my SVG Images Invisible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

https://codepen.io/ffhighwind/pen/BxNKXy

I'm converting some buttons from SVG circles to images on a canvas. I know the images work because I've seen them at the bottom of the page when I had them as `<img>` elements and tested all of them directly. I'm trying to make the SVG images visible and show up at the X,Y coordinates that my SVG circles are currently at.

**Images links (top of JS)**

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

var nodes = {
  'A0': { x: 1013, y: 1126, type: 6, links: ['A1', 'N0', 'N7', 'R4', 'H0'] },
  'A1': { x: 920, y: 1130, type: 4, links: ['A0', 'A2'] },
   ...
};

var nodeImages = [
  "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1OOiO-LxKoGWniL0j1YNRzbc9IcrZSDk3", //0 Strength
  "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1OOiO-LxKoGWniL0j1YNRzbc9IcrZSDk3", //1 Endurance
   ... 
];
```

**Image Constructor (middle of JS)**

```
function createImage(src, x, y, w, h) {
  var newElement = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'image');
  newElement.setAttribute('xlink:href', src);
  newElement.setAttribute('width', w);
  newElement.setAttribute('height', h);
  newElement.setAttribute('position', 'relative');
  newElement.setAttribute('top', x);
  newElement.setAttribute('left', y);
  newElement.setAttribute('z-index', 2);
  return newElement;
}
```

**Creating the Images (bottom of JS)**

```
//initialize data
try {
  for (var key in nodes) {
    var n = nodes[key];
    n.state = nodeState.unselected;
    var image = createImage(nodeImages[n.type], n.x, n.y, 35, 35);
    image.id = n.id + '_img';
    svg.appendChild(image); // IMAGE IS INVISIBLE??
    ...
    //generate nodes/buttons
    var btn = createButton(key, n.x, n.y, nodeTypes[n.type]); // IMAGES REPLACING THIS
    svg.appendChild(btn); // IMAGES REPLACING THIS
```

I've tried the above snippet with hard coded coordinates instead of n.x and n.y as well.

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Look at the title.

Comment: @Kokogino The title isn't a question, though.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the images are invisible? I need them to cover all of the circular nodes on the tree.

Comment: Not answering any questions but just want to say, that image takes some skill!